# UIButton inside ScrollView does not receive touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've already seen some similar questions around there, but none of them had a working answer to my problem.

My structure of Views are:

[VIEW]
[ScrollView]
[PAGE 1][PAGE 2][PAGE 3][PAGE 4]

In page 4 I have:

[PAGE 4]
[ImageView][Button]

Everything are being displayed correctly, but my button receives no touches.

I've tried some solutions from foruns and tutorials, my code for my ScrollView subclass is currently this one:

TutorialScrollView.m

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview{

self.delegate = self;
self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
self.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view{

return ![view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UIView *hitView = [self hitTest:[(UITouch*)[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self] withEvent:event];
if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    [(UIButton*)hitView sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I've noticed that the method -touchesShouldCancelInContentView is not called in Page 4 only, in all other pages its called normally.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could link your uibutton to an ibaction, so you don't need touchesbegan...

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender{

    //do stuff

}
```

Comment: That was obvioustly my first guess, but the button really ignores touches at all, it doesn't even change state to pressed